# How to create and compare a 32 byte hash of a string in solidity 0.5

Tags: solidity, hash

I simply want to create a 32 byte hash of a string and compare equality to another one, but this is proving almost impossible for some reason. E.g:

`hash("a") == hash("b")`

My compiler throws errors if I try to use `keccak256`: `TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from string memory to bytes memory requested. This function requires a single bytes argument` as this only seems to be able to take `bytes memory`. Hashes created by `abi.encode` are not comparable with `==` and are also not of a fixed length it seems so this also doesn't seem to be a solution.

I am new to programming in Solidity, so any help would be great; I am using solidity 0.5.0!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract Hasher {

    function compare(string memory a, string memory b) public pure returns(bool) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(b));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can we do directly `keccak256(a) == keccak256(b)` ? @Rob Hitchens B9lab